# Django multiple objects CRUD and a smart urls system

Tags: django, url, django-urls

-*not a exactly a question but more of a discussion*-

Dear Django devs ,

using Django to build an app , where there is multiple objects;
like client , order , item ,  supplier .. etc. Every object would have a Basic CRUD , right?
so urls.py will look something like this

```
client **display a CBV list
client/add
client/123/edit
client/123/delete
```

& again same pattern for *orders*

```
order
order/add
order/123/edit
order/123/delete
...and so on
```

I see this as a CLEAR violation to the DRY principle , and also an optimization problem having to match all lots on unnecessary entries before having a match.
, instead , we can capture first part (client for example) & send it as an argument to a ***sub urls.py*** handling the commands on this object (like the project->app but with **Deeper level(s)**)

i followed the same technique of several settings file described here http://www.slideshare.net/jacobian/the-best-and-worst-of-django (start slide 45) 
with urls.py ..

so we have two main routes to go from here:

1- for each model we have a urls file attaching the main CRUD views to each url.

2 a more generic route , handling crud for all object, but this route encourage a helper function (mainly deciding which view to load) which i sense that it's not encouraged , also i'm not quite sure how to handle reverse() in such a situation.

Any ideas , elaboration , insights ?!

Comment: after all this time, did you solve this issue and if so, some pointers you may provide?

Comment: at first, i solved via url(r'order',include(order_urls)) but that led to chaos in url files, but Now, The solution i implement is a url pattern list generator, much like what Django admin do.

Answer (score 1):

I like very much the concept and ideas behind http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

`Routers` and  `ViewSet` build automatically your CRUD urls.